# CodeIgniter PHP Combing all rows in Database to display one value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by, sum

I'm looking for some help, I'm looking to show a numeric value which is a combination of my table which looks like this

```
FinPlanIncomeID (PK)
FinancialPlanID (FK)
Weekly (int)
Fortnightly (int)
Monthly (int)
```

I want all the rows of weekly fortnightly and monthly all to add up to make a master value so what I have done so far is this.

Model.php

```
    public function getIncome($data) {            

    $condition = "Debt.[DebtID] = '".$data."' AND ";    
    $condition .= "fp.[FinancialPlanID] = fpi.[FinancialPlanID] AND ";
    $condition .= "Debt.[DebtID] = fp.[DebtID] AND ";
    $condition .= "fp.[Active] = 1 AND ";
    $condition .= "Debt.[clientid] IN (SELECT [client_id] FROM [ClientPortal].[dbo].[ci_user_access] WHERE [user_id] = '".$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']."')";


    $this->db->select ('fp.[DebtID], fp.[Active], fpi.[FinancialPlanID], fpi.[weekly], fpi.[fortnightly], fpi.[monthly], fpi.[weekly]*4 AS totalweekly, fpi.[monthly] AS totalmonthly, fpi.[fortnightly]*2 AS totalfortnightly');
    $this->db->from('[Focus].[dbo].[FinPlanIncome] AS fpi');
    $this->db->join('[Focus].[dbo].[FinancialPlan] AS fp', 'fp.[FinancialPlanID] = fpi.[FinancialPlanID]');
    $this->db->join('[Focus].[dbo].[Debt] AS Debt', 'fp.[DebtID] = Debt.[DebtID]');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
            }
```

Controller.php

```
   public function overview()
    {


    if($this->_core())
    {
        $income = $this->accounts_database->getincome($this->session->userdata('debtid'));

        $data = array(
            'income1'       => $income[0]['totalmonthly'],
            'income2'       => $income[0]['totalfortnightly'],
            'income3'       => $income[0]['totalweekly']
            );

        $this->load->view('account_overview_view',$data);

    }
}
```

View.php

```
<td>Income: <?php  $total = $income1 + $income2 + $income3; print($total); ?> </td>
```

Ive tried to cut done most of my code just to show you the parts that matter. So in a nutshell I am trying to take all my rows of weekly, fortnightly and Monthly and combine them as a master table as $total on view so that they display the value, what I have there works but it only adds my first row and doesn't do the rest.

Any help would be great.

Edit: Working SQL

```
SELECT 
      ISNULL((SUM (ISNULL(fpi.weekly, 0)) * 4) + SUM (ISNULL(fpi.monthly, 0)) + (SUM (ISNULL(fpi.fortnightly, 0)) * 2), 0) 
FROM FinancialPlan AS fp
INNER JOIN dbo.FinPlanIncome AS fpi 
    ON fp.FinancialPlanID = fpi.FinancialPlanID
WHERE DebtID = 1
AND Active = 1`
```

Comment: Do you want to add them up per column, or per row? It's a little unclear from your description I think.

Comment: Sorry I may have made it unclear basiclly if I have the row of 10, 100, 1000, 10 being weekly so on. and another row that shows 20, 200, 2000 I want it to combine all those together so that it will have a total of  3330.

Comment: Why not combine the values in SQL?

Comment: Thats what I'm sort of asking how to do as I tried select_sum but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be able to use something like`SELECT sum(col1+ col2+ col3) as total FROM table` - but you'll only be able to do this if it's the only thing you're selecting, as you're summing rows AND columns.

Comment: Do you know how to lay that out in codeignighter? as ive got this working in SQL its just not coming across in codeigniter

Comment: nvm I have sorted the issue and resolved it myself :)